# (Python) Difference of two unevenly nested lists of objects, elementwise

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have two unevenly nested lists of numbers,

```
lst1 = [0.1, [0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, [0.7, 0.8], 0.9]]
```

and

```
lst2 = [0.1, [0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, [0.1, 0.1], 0.1]]
```

I would like to take the difference `lst1 - lst2`, elementwise, to obtain

`lst1 - lst2 = [0.1, [0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, [0.6, 0.7], 0.8]]`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the two lists are guaranteed to have the same shape, you can recursively subtract corresponding elements.

```
def diff(lst1, lst2):
   return [x - y if instance(x, float) else diff(x, y) for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it recursively: iterating throug list if current pair of elements is lists and regular subtracting otherwise:

```
def subtract(entity1, entity2):
    result = []
    if isinstance(entity1, list):
        assert isinstance(entity2, list)
        for el1, el2 in zip(entity1, entity2):
            result.append(subtract(el1, el2))
    else:
        result = entity1 - entity2
    return result


lst1 = [0.1, [0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, [0.7, 0.8], 0.9]]
lst2 = [0.1, [0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, [0.1, 0.1], 0.1]]

subtract(lst1, lst2)
```

Output:

```
[0.0,
 [0.1, 0.19999999999999998],
 [0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, [0.6, 0.7000000000000001], 0.8]]
```